# applying different filters

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, core-image

I want to ask that i am using core image and applying  some filter is used this filter

```
filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIVignette" 
                                  keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, 
                        @"inputIntensity", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8], nil];
    CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
```

but i wan to know that how i implement other filters i tried but app crashes so i want to apply like these filters which is built in i chech using log

```
    CISourceOutCompositing,
    CISourceOverCompositing,
    CIStraightenFilter,
    CIStripesGenerator,
    CITemperatureAndTint,
    CIToneCurve,
    CIVibrance,
    CIVignette,
    CIWhitePointAdjust
```

Now i want to apply these filters. Which methods i should use?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail the problems you're having? What error message do you get when it crashes? What problems are you having with the other filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some, but not all of those filters aren't available on iOS.  It took me a while to notice that, too.

If you look at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html

The filters that work in iOS5 will say "Available in Mac OS X v10.4 and later and in iOS 5.0 and later.", but a lot of them just say "Available in Mac OS X v10.4".  If you try and chain multiple CoreImage filters, and one of them isn't available, you'll get no result back from one of the filters.  The CoreImage behavior when a filter isn't available is to return nil.

As a side note, GPUImage (https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) may do what you're looking for.  It can apply a filter to a UIImage or alter a live stream from the camera, and it's compatible with iOS4, if that matters.

Comment: i want to apply core images class

Comment: like how i apply different filters simple is that like how  to what values should be in civector

Answer (score 8):

Just log this:

```
NSArray *properties = [CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:
                           kCICategoryBuiltIn];
    NSLog(@"%@", properties);
    for (NSString *filterName in properties) {
        CIFilter *fltr = [CIFilter filterWithName:filterName];
        NSLog(@"%@", [fltr attributes]);
    }
```

And you will get all the filter names and the attributes you need to assign to them. Once you have all the keys, it's easy.

e.g.log o/p -

```
 CIAttributeFilterDisplayName = Vibrance;
    CIAttributeFilterName = CIVibrance;
    inputAmount =     {
        CIAttributeClass = NSNumber;
        CIAttributeDefault = 0;
        CIAttributeIdentity = 0;
        CIAttributeMax = 1;
        CIAttributeMin = "-1";
        CIAttributeSliderMax = 1;
        CIAttributeSliderMin = "-1";
        CIAttributeType = CIAttributeTypeScalar;
    };
    inputImage =     {
        CIAttributeClass = CIImage;
        CIAttributeType = CIAttributeTypeImage;
    };
```

From this you can figure out that for the filter CIVibrance you have the key inputAmount.
You can write it as:

```
CIFilter* filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIVibrance"
                                  keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey,beginImage,@"inputAmount",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8], nil];
```